# Can't access to my Google Cloud's App from http://localhost:8080

Tags: google-app-engine, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

http://localhost:8080 is not working to test my app. I am trying to make a script running on Google App Engine, I did the local development of my app and I want to test it locally before deploying everything.

http://localhost:8080 shows the Unable to Connect screen (as if it doesn't exist).

Ubuntu 16.04.1

Comment: Did you check the instructions for running your GAE app locally? (the proper ones for your project, of course - you didn't give any details about it)

Comment: @DanCornilescu Don't I just have to run "dev_appserver.py ."?

Comment: All good it works now, miraculously.

Comment: Good to hear. I was gonna say that how exactly `dev_appserver.py` is executed matters, depending on the app.